# Turn row values into variable labels

Tags: r, label

I have a messy dataset that is like this:

```
Q1 <- "Age"
Q2 <- "Sex"
Q3 <- "Age"
Q4 <- "Race"
df <- data.frame(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)
```

[image]

How do I turn every value of row 1 into variable label?
i.e: into something like this:

```
library(labelled)
var_label(df$Q1) <- "Age"
var_label(df$Q2) <- "Sex"
var_label(df$Q3) <- "Age"
var_label(df$Q4) <- "Race"
```

[image]

I have a large dataset with many variables. Is there a faster and efficient way to do this? How do I turn every value of row 1 into variable label?

I would appreciate all the help there is! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `var_label` can take a vector of `data.frame` as input, so, we can use

```
var_label(df) <- df[1, , drop = FALSE]
```

-output

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Q1: chr "Age"
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Age"
 $ Q2: chr "Sex"
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Sex"
 $ Q3: chr "Age"
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Age"
 $ Q4: chr "Race"
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Race"
```

Comment: Actually when I try to drop the first row after running this code, the labels are gone again. Is there a way to drop the first row and keep the labels?

Comment: @Bruh I think the `[` will reset the attributes, you may need to assign the attributes from the original data to the subset after doing that

Comment: @Bruh You could do something like `df2 <- df[-1, , drop = FALSE]; var_label(df2) <- df[1, , drop = FALSE]`

Comment: Great, this works! I also tried the following and it also worked.
`var_label(df) <- df[1, , drop = TRUE]; labs <- label(df);df <- df[-1,];label(df) <- as.list(labs[match(names(df), names(labs))])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first row as the var label, and then drop the first from from the dataframe

```
var_label(df)=as.character(unlist(df[1,]))

df=df[-1,]
```

hope it helps